# Why does assigning 'undefined' to variable of type {abc|undefined} cause typescript error "implicitly has type 'any'"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

This was the minimal example where I could replicate this behavior.

No error:

```
/** @param {(arg: string)=>Promise<string>} func */
async (func) => {
  /** @type {string|undefined} */
  let foo;
  while (true) {
    const bar = foo ? "a" : "b";
    foo = await func(bar);
  }
};
```

Error on `bar`:

```
/** @param {(arg: string)=>Promise<string>} func */
async (func) => {
  /** @type {string|undefined} */
  let foo = undefined;
  while (true) {
    const bar = foo ? "a" : "b";
    foo = await func(bar);
  }
};
```

Aside from seemingly not making a difference if `undefined` was actively assigned, it doesn't make sense as bar can only ever evaluate to a string, right? It also strikes me strange that it needs to be async for this to occur.

Comment: The same error shows up even if you use TS type annotations instead of JSDoc: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAFAMwK7QFz2AJwObpAF0wEsJsBKAXgD4AFTAewFsiQBTAHgONKrJmpgBvAFAwYAG1b4YCevTyES2AD4oAJqwQlWagNyiYAdwAWRSfEJJWfEWLFR6EAjABGWfjLkwA-DABEwH4w6H4ufvp2nvQewIbARNLI0HBumGQRMAC+wpn6wqCQsIgoUOhwWLgwXEqUtAzMbJyKPHwCthJSUQrcKuqa2moefVoQOhkmZqwWmFY2BvaOzqkestG+AUEhYRliqzFxCTIlKVjpBtm5QA)

Comment: Already thought so, thereby the typescript flag, but thanks for verifying :)

Comment: This is a design limitation, see [ms/TS#43047](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43047); essentially the TS type inference algorithm happens to encounter a circularity when trying to deal with this code, but doesn't with slightly different code.  It's not something that could be explained in detail without stepping through the compiler. Generally speaking, if `bar` depends on `foo` and `foo` depends on `bar`, then you might end up with a circularity warning if `bar` is not annotated. Does that address the question fully (even if unsatisfying)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I can write up an answer unless I'm missing something about the question. Let me know (and mention @jcalz to notify me if you do reply)

Comment: I can also say that this is fixed in [ms/TS#51126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51126) but it hasn't been merged (yet) so I don't know if we can expect this to start working or not soon.  See [the playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6vnGw).

Comment: Firstly thanks for the reply. It partly makes sense and seems like more of a "bug" than feature. 
Albeit it is surprising, as if you do the same with func being synchronous (instead of async), the error disappears.
That would lead me to believe it might be a different issue still, but I guess at this level my guess really is a guess.